# how to completly control audio devices in windows?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, audio

i am unable to find any switch application or system setting that i can use to switch between audio devices on my laptop.
[Sound control panel(recording)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFAIL.png), [Sound control panel(playback)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzKzF.png)
windows has only one input/output(realtek audio) for inbuilt speaker, mic and for earphones that i plugged into my laptop's 3.5mm jack. In sound control there is no separate devices for my earphones and my inbuilt speakers. that means i cannot manually set inbuilt speaker or earphones speaker to audio output. For example- if i want to use laptop inbuilt speaker for audio output and my earphones mic as a audio input then i am unable to do that.
As laptop has inbuilt speakers and mic for audio output and input, similarly earphones also has mic and drivers for input and output so there should be four combinations of input and output like:-

1. mic(earphone) and driver(earphone)
2. mic(laptop) and speaker(laptop)
3. mic(earphones) and speaker(laptop)
4. mic(laptop) and driver(earphones)

first and second is default but i am interested in third combination.

Linux help me achieve that but i dont find that functionality in windows.
Please help me so that i can add that functionality in windows, as i sit in online classes about 4 hr longs so i find it difficult to put the earphones and my laptop mic quality is not good.

Comment: How are you trying to set these devices?

Comment: windows setting or control panel.

Comment: In *Control Panel > Sound > Playback*, find the audio device and click on "Properties". Under the "Advanced" tab, do you see an option similar to "Separate all input jacks as independent input devices"?

Comment: There is no such option and there are two jack information available in the properties of playback device after pluging the earphones. Here see - [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1woLpwm370NmQAyM7paQBRUrjKg1OGfZw/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: Your image requires requesting permission, which I won't do.

Comment: i made the [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1woLpwm370NmQAyM7paQBRUrjKg1OGfZw/view?usp=sharing) accessable. please check and suggest me a solution.

Comment: Have you installed the [Realtek High Definition Audio Driver](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19336/realtek-high-definition-audio-driver-for-windows-10-windows-11-for-intel-nuc8i7be-nuc8i5be-nuc8i3be-products.html)?

Comment: it already installed with the windows update

Answer (score 0):

It depends what SW you are using for online classes.
For example, Teams let you set up mic and speakers separately. Just click three dots next to your name, Settings, Devices.
[Teams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4Bjw.png)

So what SW are you using? Please check in setting if there is such option.
Alternatively, you can try to disable you internal mic in device manager so that way you will theoretically have only one mic - your earphones mic.
Click on start, type "Device manager", open it, unpack Audio inputs and outputs, right click your internal laptop mic and choose disable device.
[Audio devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sw4E8.png)

Please vote up if my answer helped you.

Thanks.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: it is possible only when system recognizes my earphones and laptop inbuilt speaker/mic separately but that not the case. I can  switch to earphones or inbuilt mic/speaker with the application **Waves MaxxAudioPro** but cannot use the combination of both,

Comment: Please, what application do you use for online classes?